# pointers and the difference between a=1 and *a =1

Tags: c, pointers

Can someone please explain to me the difference between say `a=1` and `*a=1` in C.  I'm having difficulty conceptualizing how pointers are used.

Comment: What is the type of `a` ?

Comment: int a.....would that fundamentally change anything if it was say a char?

Comment: It would make a difference if it was an `int` or `int *`.

Comment: What did you find out by your own research? What about pointers in your C book **specifically** did you not understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a = 1` assigns `1` to `a`.

`*a = 1` assigns `1` to the memory location that `a` points to. (Note that `a` has to be a pointer for this to compile.)